# Why is \txt element of \xymatrix moved downwards?

Tags: positioning, vertical-alignment, xy-pic

I wonder why is the textual "A" in `\xymatrix{A \ar[r] & \txt{A}}` moved downwards. All I want is to have textual elements in `xymatrix` with possibility of line breaks inside the element. I thought `\txt` is for this but the positioning seems weird to me.

*EDIT*: Thank you for answers. I have found following solution: Just put there `*\txt{}` instead of `\txt{}`. Actually then there is no spacing around the text, so `*+\txt{}` looks better. I just wonder if this is standard way to do it. It seems to me that there should be a standard way to do it, since it looks like standard demand to have textual multiline entries, but both your answers look like workarounds.

Comment: The positioning of `\txt` with one line argument is mysterious; with two or more lines it's basically vertically centered with respect to the arrow stem.

Comment: I had already discovered `*+\txt{}`, but the baseline is still weird. I've used `\xymatrix`often in the past, but `\txt` only for placing text over arrows. Probably it is not meant to be used in the way you do.

Comment: @karlkoeller: The documentation says otherwise. See section 3 in http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xwchen/Useful%20files/xyguide.pdf . It says it is meant to be used like this.

Comment: @user87690 Yes, you're right. It seems that `*+\txt{}` is the way it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 4):

The positioning of text inside `\txt` is really strange...

As a workaround, add the following lines in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\xydef@\txt@ii#1{\vbox{\vspace*{-7pt}%
 \let\\=\cr
 \tabskip=\z@skip \halign{\relax\hfil\txtline@@{##}\hfil\cr\leavevmode#1\crcr}}}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\makeatletter
\xydef@\txt@ii#1{\vbox{\vspace*{-7pt}%
 \let\\=\cr
 \tabskip=\z@skip \halign{\relax\hfil\txtline@@{##}\hfil\cr\leavevmode#1\crcr}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{A \ar[r] & \txt{A}}

\bigskip

\xymatrix{A \ar[r] & \txt{A\\B}}

\bigskip

\xymatrix{A \ar[r] & \txt{A\\B\\C}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

it is set in mathmode by default and `\txt` uses the text mode. If you want an upright `A` use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{A \ar[r] & \mathrm{A}}

\end{document}
```

if you want real text, then use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newcommand\TXT[2][t]{\tabular[#1]{l}#2\endtabular}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{A \ar[r] & \TXT{name of \\ class of spaces}}

\xymatrix{A \ar[r] & \TXT[b]{name of \\ class of spaces}}

\xymatrix{A \ar[r] & \TXT[c]{name of \\ class of spaces}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to overwrite the existing `\txt`:

```
\renewcommand\txt[2][t]{...}
```

Comment: But I don't want mathematical upright A, I really want to put text there like `\txt{name of class of spaces}` or `\txt{name of // class of spaces}`. I was just wondering why it moves downwards.

Comment: I don't know what `\txt` really does without looking into the code of `xy`. However, use `\textrm{...}` instead. See edited answer.

Comment: Sorry, I really meant `\txt{name of \\ class of spaces}` as an example when I want a line break in the text element.

Comment: ok, see my next edit